# Is there anyway to count specific emojis under the message? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm making a poll command for my discord bot. I use emojis to vote for poll options.

I want my bot to show the results of the poll after some period of time (I didn't implement timeout yet). But to do it I need to count each emoji. Is there anyway of doing it?

My code so far:

```
@bot.command(name='poll')
async def poll(ctx, question, option1 = None, option2 = None):
    if option1 == None and option2 == None:
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title="Poll",
            description=f"{question}",
            color = discord.Color.blue()
        )
        msg = await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
        message = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(msg.id)
        await message.add_reaction("")
        await message.add_reaction("")
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title="Poll",
        description=f"{question}",
        color=discord.Color.blue()
    )
    embed.add_field(name=f"{option1}", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name=f"{option2}", inline=False)
    msg = await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
    message = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(msg.id)
    await message.add_reaction("")
    await message.add_reaction("")
```

Answer (score 0):

Emoji are just characters, like any other:

```
>>> st="The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"
>>> st.count("")
2
```

and in case you don't have a fancy emoji-keyboard (`ord()` is the inverse of `chr()`):

```
>>> ord("")
128077
>>> ord("")
128078
```

Update - try:

```
for reaction in message.reactions:
  if reaction.emoji == "":
    counts[""] += reaction.count
```

based on these:

- https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.reactions
- https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Reaction

Comment: Maybe I've made my point wrong, I need to count amount reactions (those emojis that appear under the message). I dont know how to access them

Comment: `message.reactions` are the reactions to the message, not the emojis it contains.

Comment: Unless I'm reading this wrong, the docs disagree: `message.reactions` should return a list of `Reaction` objects, each which contain both `.emoji` and `.count` properties. ->  `reactions
Reactions to a message. Reactions can be either custom emoji or standard unicode emoji.

Type
List[Reaction]`